# my printf isnt showing up when handling sigaction until i exit

Tags: c, unix, signals

I am new to signals in Unix, the purpose of this exercice is to disable SIGINT for stopping the program and use  SIGQUIT instead, and it is successfully ignoring SIGINT when i press ctrl-c but the printf isnt showing until i press the Ctrl-/ which is for the SIGQUIT, and all the messages appear at once.

Example: if i press ctrl-c 4 times then ctrl-/:
 Only after pressing ctrl-\ i get 4 messages saying i have pressed Ctrl-c then the quitting you sent the SIGQUIT signal.

If i press ctrl-c only i get nothing but at least it is being ignored

```
struct sigaction action;

void hand(int sig)
{
    switch(sig){
    case SIGINT:
        printf("You have presed ctrl-c");
        break;
    case SIGQUIT:
        printf("Quittin you sent a SIGQUIT signal");
        exit(SIGQUIT);
        break;
    default:
        printf("WRONG SIGNAL");
        exit(-1);
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{       
    action.sa_handler=hand;
    printf("Ctrl-C disabled, press Ctrl-/ to quit...\n");
    sigaction(SIGINT,&action,NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT,&action,NULL);
    while(1){
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: `printf("You have presed ctrl-c");` --> `printf("You have presed ctrl-c\n");` BTW you must avoid to use printf in a signal handler

Comment: @LPs thank you! it worked, but why?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! @ChrisTurner

Comment: Becasue of it is stdout is buffered. So `\n` will swicth to "new line"

Comment: Note that `exit` is not async-signal-safe, `_exit` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues here.  First, `printf` is line buffered by default and your aren't printing a newline, so the output buffer may not be flushed when you expect.  Second, the `printf` function is *not* async-signal-safe, meaning it's undefined behavior to call it in a signal handler.

Change your signal handler to set a flag instead of printing, then check that flag in your loop and print (with `\n` at the end of the string) if it is set.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @dbush answer, you can use [`write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) in the signal handler, it is [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and no buffering delays its output.

Example:

```
static char const msg[] = "You have presed ctrl-c\n";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
```